# Accessing parent iframe from a childs iframe

Tags: iframe, parent-child, parent

Okay, I have an html page with two iframes on it so.

```
-------------------------------------------------
|              PARENT                           |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|     [iframe1 id=i1 name=i1]                   |    
|                                               |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|     [iframe2 id=i2 name=i2]                   |
|                                               |
|                                               |
-------------------------------------------------
```

When I click on a link in iframe1, i need the resulting page to display in iframe2. I have tried:

```
<a href=blah.html target=parent.i2>link</a>
```

but that does not work.

any one know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might need JavaScript.  Something like

```
 onclick="javascript:parent.i2.document.location='blah.html'"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href=blah.html target="i2">link</a>
```

You just need to put "i2" it should be unique window name in this page. No need to specify parent etc.

Comment: This is a much better answer than mine.

Comment: Thanks, but your answer is good too, its all just different ways.